# What to do with matrices that bigger than the amount of memory on GPU on tensorflow?

Tags: matrix, tensorflow, deep-learning

One-hot-vectors for NLP tasks have about 10000 dimensions and I want to process them by RNN with hidden-state size about 50000. So, for LSTM-RNN I need to have about 4 matrices 50000*50000 and 4 matrices 10000*50000, and about 10 vectors with size 10000. If we calculate the total size that I need to store all these stuff It will be about 20-30 GB of memory.

Is there some approach for solving this problem?